# Show distinct id once with multiple rows of data

Tags: ms-access

What I have for data:

```
Bob | 1
Bob | 2
Bob | 3
Jane| 5
Jane| 27
```

Basically I want to sort this out in either the query or report so I can come out with this as a result:

```
Bob | 1
    | 2
    | 3
Jane| 5
    | 27
```

Do I have to use VBA to come up with this solution or is there a workaround either in the query or in the report functionality? I'm just getting used to using Access, so I'm looking for some pointers.

Comment: The VBA way of doing this seems like more work than necessary for something so simple. Is there a way I can filter in the Report phase?

Answer (score 0):

For those that are looking in the future, I had multiple other columns of data that correlated to the one 'name' I wanted to separate out. If you sort by group, you can make the name the 'group name' and all the values will still correlate to that group if you leave them under your details tab in the report.